# Can I visit France with this Greek Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

Can I visit France with this Greek Schengen visa?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a type D visa (that is, a national long-stay visa) issued by Greece.

**In addition to** the right to stay in Greece, this visa *also* allows you to make *short visits* to any other Schengen country, including France.

"Short" visits means that those visits must comply with the usual 90-of-every-180-days rule for short Schengen visits -- with the modification that days you spend in Greece do *not* count as "Schengen days" for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much Henning. By the way, I also heard that there is no control at all in the airport (in France) because it's a Schengen flight, is this true ?

Comment: @mbarkimohamed: Officially and in principle there are no systematic passport checks on a flight from Greece to France. However, French authorities are still jittery after terrorist attacks in 2015 and 2016, so it is possible that you may pass through an "officially not systematic" control upon arriving in France.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Rarely happens in practice, but yes, not impossible